# Simple Linear Regression Question

Tags: statistics, regression

Let $Y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}X_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$ be a simple linear regression model with independent errors and iid normal distribution.  If $X_{i}$ are fixed what is the distribution of $Y_{i}$ given $X_{i} = 10$?

I am preparing for a test with questions like these but I am realizing I am less up to date on these things than I thought.  Could anyone explain the thought process used to approach this kind of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then, we have:

$$Y_i \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i,\sigma^2)$$

Further clarification:

The above uses the following facts:

(a) Expectation is a linear operator,

(b) Variance of a constant is $0$,

(c) Covariance of a random variable with a constant is $0$ and finally,

(d) A linear combination of normals is also a normal.

Does that help?

Comment: I think I see why that's true since the mean of the line is shifted from the mean of the error BECAUSE they're independent, right?.  But I think I am more lost than that, I can't put together how $X_{i}$ being fixed, independent errors or any of that affects the question.  Can we in some way split that term, the line you wrote, up since the errors are independent?

Comment: That does help a lot, I really appreciate it as I would not have seen all those moving parts.  How is expectation being a linear operator used here?  I mean I understand at the basic level that (redacted - incorrect) but you're applying that somewhere in the background I think. In fact the one part I do see the use of is that a linear combination of normals is also normal.

Comment: $E(Y_i) = E(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i) = E(\beta_0) + E(\beta_1 X_i) + E(\epsilon_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i $

Comment: I had that backwards as well!  Clearly expectation of a constant is constant, and $E(e)$ = 0 seems familiar too but I can't pinpoint why it's true.

Comment: That is by assumption. Look up the assumptions of the linear regression model.

Comment: Is it related to the assumption that the sum of residuals is zero? In either case I will certainly review that.  This has definitely helped me figure out where to begin review.

Comment: Not exactly. The observation that the sum of residuals is zero is a consequence of how we estimate the parameters of the model rather than an assumption per se.

Comment: Right, I found a list of the assumptions.  In the back of my mind I was hoping there would be a more elegant explanation.  Thank you again, I'll leave the discussion here to prevent the comments from getting any larger.